# Querying information for HTTPBasicAuth

Tags: python, mysql, authentication, peewee

For my site for auth I'm using https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . Now I'm trying to make it that it's using data from database. To do that i created database named Users and created columns named username and password.

To get data from this table after defining its class as model I've made get_user functions which looks like it:

```
@staticmethod
    def get_user():
        query = (Users
                 .select())
        user = []
        for s in query:
            user.append(s)

        return user
```

(I'm not sure if it's correct)

Next I had to modify get_pw function but I also wasn't sure how to modify it so I made it look like it:

```
@auth.get_password
    def get_pw(username):
        if username in Users.get_user():
            return users.get(Users.get_user())
        return None
```

Now after running the site I get prompt to give login and password but those that I set up in my database doesn't seem to work so there must be a problem with get_pw function. Also I'm using peewee SQL to manage database : http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of your `get_user` method since you are issuing a very large select query that fetches all records from user table. The `get_pw` can be redefined as:

```
def get_pw(username):
    user = Users.get(Users.name == username) #assuming you have a username field in model
    return user.password #assuming a password field
```

Also, its a good practice to define your model class as a singular noun rather than plural. So, its better to call it **User** rather than **Users**.

This'll help you get started in no time: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#quickstart